# How can I seal an interior door

Tags: insulation, doors, door-frame

One of my bedroom doors has gaps at the bottom and side. How can I close or seal these gaps. I would like to heat only this room and prevent loss of heat to other rooms.

The gap at the bottom is from 1/2 to 3/4 inch. The floor of the room has a carpet.

The gap on the side with the door knob is the largest.

Weather striping products and door sweeps seem to be for external doors.

Comment: Saves money  on heat. But how much will the plumbing bill be after the pipes freeze?

Comment: Not sure how the plumbing is relevant

Comment: You only heat one room. Pipes freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-adhesive foam tape and bristle-type weather sealing options (including sweeps) abound at your local hardware store or big box retailer. What makes a particular product "for external doors"? Seems like that's exactly what you need.

I'd opt for the softest foam available or a felt or bristle product to minimize impact noise and closing effort.

Comment: I had purchased the rubber based door sweep which seemed like the wrong choice for a carpet based floor. I suppose that the bristle type is what I need to use.

Comment: The side and top weatherstrip kit I got has a aluminum strip of width 1" and foam that is around 1/2" uncompressed. The interior door only has a 1" frame. I need something thinner.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy foam strips with one side adhesive. They sell it in most home improvement stores. There is different widths available. I recently bought 1/2in roll to seal my locker at work to prevent dust from getting in and it has worked perfectly, for the bottom of the door look for the bristled type that screw to the bottom of the door they work well with carpeted floors. When you install it let it sit on the floor, don't push it into the carpet or it will make the door hard to open and will wear marks into the carpet